# Knockout Observable of type number defaults to 0 in textbox

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I am either missing something or I have been working too much today.  I have a knockout observable set to type number.  When I initialize it to null, the textbox in HTML is defaulting to 0.  I want the textbox to be empty.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Price:</label><i class="required"></i>
    <input id="price" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: productPrice" />
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
productPrice: KnockoutObservable<number>;
this.productPrice = ko.observable(null)
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works fine. You can see the demo here :

http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/1Ly9mxt3/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Price:</label><i class="required"></i>
    <input id="price" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: productPrice" />
</div>
```

JS

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.productPrice = ko.observable(null);    
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

## Solution:

You have other javascript that sets it to `0`.

Comment: Thanks, you were right.  I had another call in an initializer method that was setting it to 0